# Как сделать Sendmail-заглушку для локального сервера XAMPP?

Tags: php, веб-сервер, xampp, lamp

Недавно я начал изучать PHP и столкнуться с проблемой создания Sendmail-заглушки для локального сервера XAMPP.
Я хочу, чтобы сообщения отправленные локально, тестировочно. Были в специальной папке sendmail.
Я отлично понимаю, что в комплекте к XAMPP'у присутствует пакет sendmail для отправки в него сообщений локально.

Так же хотелось бы увидить в каких файлах и папках нужно вносить имения, из-за обилия ответов на эту тему достаточно сложно разобраться в этом.

В качестве ОС использую Ubuntu

Ниже я предоставил код своего index.php

```
<?php

echo date('H:i:s');

$arr = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2];
echo $arr['c'];

mail('1@1.ru', 'a', 'b');
$i = 1; ?>
```

PHP-код файла mailtodisk

```
    #!/opt/lampp/bin/php
<?php
$input = file_get_contents('php://stdin');
$filename = '/opt/lampp/mailoutput/mail-' . gmdate('Ymd-Hi-s') . '.txt';
$retry = 0;
while(is_file($filename))
{
    $filename = '/opt/lampp/mailoutput/mail-' . gmdate('Ymd-Hi-s') . '-' . ++$retry . '.txt';
}
file_put_contents($filename, $input);
```

Comment: вы же не забыли в php.ini указать строку sendmail_path=/opt/lampp/mailtodisk/mailtodisk ?

Comment: Нет, она там присутствует. sendmail_path= "/opt/lampp/mailtodisk/mailtodisk"

Comment: Проверяли права на папку mailtodisk и убедились что веб-пользователь, из под которого запускаются скрипты может вести в неё запись? Если, конечно, вы запускаете из под root и/или в консоли из-под него - то вопрос не стоит.

Comment: А вы уверены в ее присутствии, распечатывали `phpinfo();` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В папке sendmail в домашней директории xampp создаем файл sendmail.php:

```
    <?php

    //папка в которую будем складывать почту
    define('DIR','c:/xampplite/tmp/sendmail/');

    //получаем из потока тело письма
    $stream = '';
    $fp = fopen('php://stdin','r');
    while($t=fread($fp,2048))
        {
        if( $t===chr(0) )
            break;
        $stream .= $t;
        }
    fclose($fp);

    //Сохраняем в файл
    $fp = fopen(mkname(),'w');
    fwrite($fp,iconv("UTF-8","CP1251",$stream));
    fclose($fp);

    //Функция присвоения имени файлу
    function mkname($i=0)
        {
        $fn = DIR.date('Y-m-d_H-i-s_').$i.'.eml';
        if ( file_exists($fn) )
            return mkname(++$i);
            else return $fn;
        }

    ?>
```

В файле \php\php.ini ищем строчку

```
    sendmail_path = "C:\xampplite\sendmail\sendmail_.exe -t"
```

```
и заменяем ее на

sendmail_path = C:\xampplite\php\php.exe c:\xampplite\sendmail\sendmail.php
```

```
    Естественно, пути нужно подправить в соответствии с той директорией, куда вы установили xampp.
    Перезапускаем сервис apache, и проверяем работу нашей заглушки - если вы все сделали правильно, все отправленные письма будут ждать вас в папке /tmp/sendmail/
```

Comment: Как описывал в теме у меня Ubuntu, я постараюсь адаптировать это под директории GNU/Linux. Ниже я перечислю выбор директории согласно своей ОС

Сразу говорю, что папки tmp в этой версии нет, так что я использую папку для mailtodisk

1. Создаю файл в директории "/opt/lampp/sendmail.php"
С тем содержимым, которые вы указали выше.
2. Меняю путь для сохранения сообщений на директорию "/opt/lampp/mailtodisk/"
3. Редактирую строку в php.ini на директорию "/opt/lampp/mailtodisk/"

И не чего не работает, браво

Comment: @FrencOlesov, что вы вставили в `sendmail_path`? Должно быть что-то типа `/usr/bin/php /opt/lampp/sendmail.php`. И приведите `ls -la /opt/lampp/mailtodisk/`

Comment: Так как насколько мне известно все файлы установщика lampp находятся в /opt/lampp/
В ini.php указано: 'sendmail_path= "/opt/lampp/mailtodisk/mailtodisk"'
'ls -la /opt/lampp/mailtodisk/'

'$ ls -la /opt/lampp/mailtodisk/
итого 12
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 мая 15 12:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 32 root root 4096 мая 16 12:08 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root  316 апр 25 14:35 mailtodisk'

Comment: @FrencOlesov попробуйте вручную запустить из консоли `/opt/lampp/mailtodisk/mailtodisk`.

Comment: @FrencOlesov вы неправильно указали параметр sendmail_path - похоже ошиблись. Нужно указать путь к скрипту и указать интерпретатор: `/usr/bin/php /opt/lampp/mailtodisk/mailtodisk/sendmail.php` - оба пути должны быть верными, так мы заставим выполниться PHP, который запустит скрипт. У скрипта должны быть права на чтение от имени веб-сервера. 664 для этих целей должно хватить. Если не сработает, выполните `/usr/bin/php /opt/lampp/mailtodisk/mailtodisk/sendmail.php` в консоли, ошибки - сюда.

Answer (score 1):

Можно в php.ini [указать директиву](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mail.configuration.php#ini.sendmail-path) `sendmail_path` с путём к Вашей заглушке.